# How do I assign a list of words in a txt file to numbers that can be chosen by rng?

Tags: java

I have a random number generator and a txt document with the 50 states in it and a scanner that reads the list, how to I get my program to print out a randomly chosen state instead of a list of a random amount of states?

this is a class project and ive used bits and pieces of different programs.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;



/**

This is intended as a starter for a word scrambler (anagram generator)

that scrambles a randomly selected word from a word file specified on the

command line.



 This program simply echos the entire contents of the file to the console.

 It assumes that the first line of the input contains the number of words in     the file

 (not including the count if you think of it as a word). 

 For this program, a word is any white space delimited sequence of characters.

 @author Charlie McDowell (minor mods Dean Bailey 08/23/07)
*/

    class Echo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

        Random rng = new Random();
        int rnum, j;
        for (j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {
            rnum = rng.nextInt(50);

            int size = in.nextInt();//first item is the number of words

            int i = 0;//changed value of "i" to the random number that is generated

            while (i++ < rnum) {
                if (i == rnum) ;
                System.out.println();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop doesn't loop.

Comment: There is not enough here to comment on.  Your println() does nothing.  Your while loop loops over a random number of values.  Try again.

Comment: It wasnt a finished code. it was an experiment and it had some parts I broke on accident. Thanks for the comments though

Answer (score 0):

I honestly have no clue what's going on in your code, so I wrote this that does what you described. (I am bored)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    Random rng = new Random();

    int size = in.nextInt();                    //Read the first line for the number of words
    in.nextLine();                              //Because nextInt doesn't move to the next line, and the for loop has to start on the first line with something on it.
    String[] lines = new String[size];          //Create an array of Strings to hold the words

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){                  //Read in the lines from the file into the array
        lines[i] = in.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(lines[rng.nextInt(size)]);       //Pick a random index from the array and display it. This can be put in a loop if multiple outputs are required.

                                                //THIS IS NOT FAULT TOLERANT; IF THE FILE CONTAINS FEWER LINES THAN ARE SPECIFIED IN THE FIRST LINE, AN ERROR WILL BE THROWN.


}
```

Comment: thank you, I will study this and my the proper adjustments to my code.